# Is it bad practice to put computational intensive code in event listeners?

Tags: android, multithreading, event-handling, event-listener

As the title said, is it bad practice to put computational intensive code in event listeners?

I'm currently working on an android project which reads sensors' data at their fastest speeds (every 10 ms). For a certain period, I'm doing tons of computation with sampled data from sensors. And right now, I'm putting my computational intensive code in the sensor event listener.

Is it possible that before I can finish my computations in the sensor event listeners, another sensor event occurs and the same sensor event listener is invoked again? Will I lose my data in this situation?

If it is not possible and the sensor event listener will block the interrupts generated by sensor reading, will I lose some sensor data if it takes so long to re-enable the ability to read in sensor data?

What's a good coding practice in this situation? Should I use multi-threading and have another thread constantly checking a flag set by the sensor event listener to start computational intensive code?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing with the data afterwards?  persisting in database, displaying to the user somehow?  I would recommend an `IntentService`.

Comment: I'm using them to train a neural network.

Comment: It's hard to say how exactly you should handle it.  My suggestion is to use an `IntentService` or `AsyncTask`.  You definitely shouldn't be doing cpu intensive operations in the receiver.

Comment: THX. will dig into that